# How to refer from one container to another using localhost

Tags: docker, networking, localhost, containers

I'm working on building docker containers for a Ruby-on-Rails project I'm currently working on, so that I can develop this project using the remote feature of Visual Studio Code. This project should still continue to work without using docker containers, so I cannot make breaking changes to the existing code that would compromise this.

The application server (Rails) needs to connect to a MySQL database that's running in a separate container. The database container is named `db`, and I can connect from the application container to this container by using the `db` hostname.

The `database.yml` config file for rails defines how to connect to the database, but this is where my problem is situated. I don't want to change the host to `db` instead of `localhost` as this would mean that regular users (that do not use Docker containers) will no longer be able to connect to the database without changing this file. How can I somehow start or change my docker config so that `db` is accessible as `localhost` instead of `db` inside of the application container?

`database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  username: ****
  password: ****
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: ****
  # setup local port forwarding for this to work
  host: db
  port: 3306
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    build: ./unipept-db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ****
      MYSQL_USER: ****
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    hostname: mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
    restart: always
  app:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: ./unipept-application
    command: sleep infinity
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    volumes:
      - ~/.gitconfig:/root/.gitconfig
      - ..:/workspace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user `network_mode: "host"`in your `APP` config then you can call the `DB`from your `APP` using `localhost:PORT`

```
phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
  app:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: ./unipept-application
    command: sleep infinity
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ~/.gitconfig:/root/.gitconfig
      - ..:/workspace
```

**PS:** Published ports are discarded when using host network mode

Comment: Thx! Is there any way to publish the port automatically using this method?

Comment: @PieterVerschaffelt In host network mode you do not need to publish port it's already available to host .

Comment: @Adiii the problem is that you can't run more than one `App` container with the same port (image)

Comment: so if he wants something like this then he should not expose port, instead, he can use docker-network.

Answer (score 0):

If you make it an environment variable in your `database.yml.erb` file, it will be configurable.  You even already have an example of this.  You can set:

```
host: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_HOST', 'localhost') %>
```

In development, just don't set the environment variable, and it will use `localhost`.  In a Docker environment, do set it, and it will use that hostname.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
```

You should also pass things like database credentials the same way.